# Как правильно спозиционировать картинку и блок с текстом в разных колонках?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, позиционирование

На странице есть длинный текст. Текст разбит на блоки так, что некоторым блокам соответствует изображение. Блоки с изображениями позиционируются в разных колонках
Пример на изображении ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот блок у меня выводится следующим кодом:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h4>ЗАГОЛОВОК</h4>
        <p>ТЕКСТ</p>
        <section>
        <h6>ЗАГОЛОВОК СПИСКА</h6>
        <ul>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №1</li>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №2</li>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №3</li>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №4</li>
        </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5" style="height: 400px;margin: 20px 0 0 0;">
        <img alt="2.jpg" src="" style="height: 100%;object-fit: cover;">
    </div>
</div>
```

На колонки я разбиваю с помощью сетки bootstrap. Проблема моих стилей в том, что я жестко задаю высоту картинки. В идеальном варианте, я ожидаю увидеть изображение высотой в блок с текстом, в котором картинка будет растягиваться либо по высоте сохраняя пропорции и обрезаясь по ширине, либо наоборот.

**Как я могу правильно спозиционировать картинку и текст?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4**:

**1.** Задать правому блоку фон в виде нужной картинки - тогда она будет автоматически растягиваться и обрезаться

**2.**  При переходе размера окна через брейкпоинт 767px блоку с картинкой задать какую-нибудь минимальную высоту (иначе он схлопнется, и фоновой картинки видно не будет)

```css
[class^="col"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.pics {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/163339/5f7e05fb-daa4-408c-9593-66fd3bef0149/s1200');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .pics {
    min-height: 200px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h4>ЗАГОЛОВОК</h4>
                    <p></p>
                    <section>
                        <h6>ЗАГОЛОВОК СПИСКА</h6>
                        <ul>
                            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №1</li>
                            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №2</li>
                            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №3</li>
                            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №4</li>
                            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №1</li>
                            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №2</li>
                            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №3</li>
                            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 pics">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Bootstrap 3**:

**1.** Задать блоку-обёртке (.row) display: flex - тогда правая колонка будет автоматически подстраиваться под высоту левой колонки с текстом

**2.** Задать правому блоку фон в виде нужной картинки - тогда она будет автоматически растягиваться и обрезаться

**3.**  При переходе размера окна через брейкпоинт 991px сменить для .row flex на block, а блоку с картинкой задать какую-нибудь минимальную высоту (иначе он схлопнется, и фоновой картинки видно не будет)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
[class^="col"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.pics {
  background-image: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/163339/5f7e05fb-daa4-408c-9593-66fd3bef0149/s1200');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .row {
    display: block;
  }
  .pics {
    min-height: 200px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h4>ЗАГОЛОВОК</h4>
        <p>ТЕКСТ</p>
        <section>
        <h6>ЗАГОЛОВОК СПИСКА</h6>
        <ul>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №1</li>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №2</li>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №3</li>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №4</li>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №1</li>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №2</li>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №3</li>
            <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №4</li>
        </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 pics">
        
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ответ полезен! Единственное, я бы не прописывал классу `row` свойство `display: flex` и `display: block`, а вместо этого создал бы уникальный класс, что бы он не конфликтовал с bootstrap

Comment: @Kyper, ну да, это логично - здесь я просто тестовый пример сделал

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю можно ли решить данную проблему на css, так как фиксированной высоты текста тоже нету. Предлагаю Вам вот такое простое решение на JS или JQuery. Для начала в стили для картинки добавьте overflow-x: hidden;, для того, что бы она не увеличивалась по ширине и задайте ей какую-то фиксированную ширину. 
Теперь к JS:

Вот решение на чистом JavaScript:

```
 var text_height = document.getElementById('id_of_text_block').clientHeight;
 document.getElementById('id_of_img').style.height = text_height + 'px';
```

А вот на jQuery, я считаю что лучше использовать его:

```
 var text_height = jQuery('#id_of_text').height();
 jQuery('#id_of_img').css('max-height', text_height);
```

Надеюсь Вам поможет.

Answer (score -1):

Надо совсем немного помочь бутстрапу.

```
.img-fluid {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
}
```

Разметка

```
<div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h4>ЗАГОЛОВОК</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus debitis nulla laboriosam? Natus amet quisquam exercitationem. Eligendi iste facilis placeat vero illo pariatur dolorum architecto cum explicabo maxime odio vitae, id fugiat. Blanditiis dolore nihil nobis officiis quasi necessitatibus incidunt aliquam corporis eum tempora animi quisquam vero totam impedit excepturi vel esse, similique voluptatem ratione magni praesentium quis consequuntur molestias provident! Quibusdam tenetur dicta sapiente saepe, omnis fugiat deleniti iusto, nam voluptatem, ipsam vero rem possimus iste iure. Fugiat ex assumenda rem nesciunt reiciendis explicabo perspiciatis magni asperiores eveniet quidem alias consectetur nemo laboriosam adipisci architecto, voluptas vitae quas saepe?      </p>
                <section>
                    <h6>ЗАГОЛОВОК СПИСКА</h6>
                    <ul>
                        <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №1</li>
                        <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №2</li>
                        <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №3</li>
                        <li>ПУНКТ СПИСКА №4</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img src="test.jpg" alt="my picture" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```